# Like function not matching similar text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare company names from a large list and unfortunately not all of the names were entered in the database exactly the same way.  Some examples of the variances are:

```
7-ELEVEN vs 7-ELEVEN, Inc.
ABBVIE vs ABBVIE, Inc.
ACTION BEHAVIOR CENTERS LLC vs ACTION BEHAVIOR CENTERS THERAPY LLC
```

When I try to use the like function to compare the names, it's returning FALSE.

```
Debug.Print Cells(i + 1, 3).Value Like Act_Name
```

How similar do they need to be for the Like function to work? Is there another way that I can compare the names to determine if they are similar?

Comment: Are you using wildcards? What is `Act_Name`? Otherwise you may need to do fuzzy matching. It may help to read the [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) documentation.

Comment: The cells(i+1,3).value would be the 1st name (7-ELEVEN) & the Act_Name would be the 2nd name (7-ELEVEN, Inc.)

Comment: You are not using `Like` correctly. `Like` allows you to use wild-cards, but it does not compute a similarity value. Read the documentation for that function if you want to use it. Otherwise, suggest you use some kind of fuzzy matching, perhaps in Power Query.

Comment: "similar" in your case might be "dissimilar" in some other case, so you won't find any easy single line of code to do the work. You provide a good example - no one could know whether Action Behavior Centers *Therapy* is the same or different company unless you tell them. Usually in this case you would just maintain a list of all company aliases and use a lookup function to get the main name.

Answer (score 0):

If company names all start the same but end differently (LLC, Inc...) then you could compare the beginnings of strings like this:

```
Sub test0()
    Dim str1, str2 As String
    str1 = Array("7-ELEVEN", _
                 "ABBVIE", _
                 "ACTION BEHAVIOR CENTERS THERAPY")
    str2 = Array("7-ELEVEN, Inc.", _
                 "ABBVIE, Inc.", _
                 "ACTION BEHAVIOR CENTERS THERAPY LLC")
    For Each s1 In str1
        For Each s2 In str2
            'non case sensitive comparison, greater than 0 is true
            If InStr(1, s2, s1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'If s2 begins with s1
                Debug.Print s1 & " = " & s2
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Another way would be to remove the LLC, Inc or any other parts before comparing strings:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim str1, str2, strTemp, removeStr As String, i As Integer
    str1 = Array("7-ELEVEN", _
                 "ABBVIE", _
                 "ACTION BEHAVIOR CENTERS THERAPY")
    str2 = Array("7-ELEVEN, Inc.", _
                 "ABBVIE, Inc.", _
                 "ACTION BEHAVIOR CENTERS THERAPY LLC")
    strTemp = str2
    strRemove = Array(", Inc.", " LLC")
    For i = LBound(str2) To UBound(str2)
        For Each sR In strRemove
            str2(i) = Replace(str2(i), sR, "")
        Next
    Next
    For Each s1 In str1
        For i = LBound(str2) To UBound(str2)
            'non case sensitive comparison, 0 is true
            If StrComp(s1, str2(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Debug.Print s1 & " = " & strTemp(i)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: Similar output from the code above]

Yet another way to compare might be using Split(str1(i), " ") and keeping count of matching non case sensitive words between strings, you could combine it with Replace(...) to remove any unexpected chars - perhaps a more complex route. Additionally, for ease of use, instead of using arrays, as I am to keep track of these values, you could use ranges, which I just noticed you're already doing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, the names of the compaines can change so hard coding the names into the Array wouldn't be an option.

Comment: If you could provide a more complete set of sample data in your post we could look into other solutions - as I've mentioned, there are other, albeit more complex solutions. Alternatively, as a commenter suggested, you could maintain a list of aliases (or similar names) separately and use a lookup function.